# Data from one table to select data columns from another table, using r

Tags: r, data-manipulation, pca

My data table, tab, is 2000 x 500, y1 = col1, y2 = col2, y3 = col3 …. Y500 = col500.  See image.

[image: partial data table]

I want to carry out some PCA work on a section of this, e.g y1 = col1, y22 = col22, y36 = col36, y41 = col41, and so on.

A separate data table, SM, contains the column ID,and refers to the columns in the main data table (tab) I want to consider.  There are 200 such entries.

Image of SM follows.

[image: Partial ID table]

The following

```
fit.std <- prcomp(tab, scale.=T)
```

Pulls in all the column entries.

If I have 200 specific columns of data to consider, entering the column numbers manually would be very time consuming and error prone.

Can someone please tell me how to take the data from column ID (in data table SM), to select the corresponding columns in the data table tab, and then include in the fit.std line?

Is there a way to take in the data in SM to enable me to select the required columns in the larger data table tab?  In order words, SM col1 would correspond to tab col1, SM col22 would correspond to tab col22, and so on.

```
fit.std <- promo(c(ID$*), scale = TRUE)
```

where ID$* contains the data table SN entries I want to match with columns in tab?

Thank you.

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding, I recommand you to provide a specific and minimum example, i.e., `table1 <- ?`, `table2 <- ?` (dimension: just give the several rows ), and your desired  result.

Comment: Peace, thx for the suggestion.  I have used a coupe of screen grabs and edited my question, to hopefully add some clarity to what I am trying to do.  I hope the screen grabs are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok based on your updated question, it looks like you want to subset the dataframe `tab`, selecting only the columns listed in `SM$ID`.

You can do that with:

```
tab[,SM$ID]
```

Comment: Akindele, that is exactly what I was looking for, and can now apply to a wide range of data sets I am working with , many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure exactly what you're asking for, but I'll try to address your task to the best of my ability.

Suppose `tab` is a dataframe with 2000 rows and 500 columns. And `SM` is a dataframe where `SM$ID` refers to columns in `tab`.

Then you can get a list of the columns referenced by `SM$ID` using:

```
list_of_cols <- lapply(SM$ID, function(x) tab[,x])
```

If you want to collapse (or "flatten") this list of vectors into a single vector you can do:

```
single_vec <- unlist(list_of_cols)
```

Comment: Akindele, thx for input.  Looking back, I submitted a poorly constructed question which was very confusing. I hope it is somewhat clearer now.